# Characterize all minimally $2$-matchable graphs

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

A finite graph is minimally $k$-matchable if it has at least $k$ distinct perfect matchings, but deleting any edge results in a graph which does not. We want to characterize all minimally $2$-matchable graphs. Any hints?

Comment: What's the most general class of examples you've thought of so far?

Comment: I thought of even cycles.

Comment: Good. Does the graph have to be connected? What about something like $C_4+K_2,$ is that minimally $2$-matchable?

Answer (score 1):

Your graph has two perfect matchings $M_1$ and $M_2$, and any edge of the graph should be contained in $M_1 \cup M_2$, since otherwise you could delete it and be left with a 2-matchable graph.

In particular, your graph has maximum degree 2, since every vertex is incident to only one edge of $M_1$ and only one edge of $M_2$ (and these might be the same edge).

It's reasonably easy to characterize all graphs with maximum degree 2, and see which ones

1. Have any perfect matchings to begin with.
2. Have at least two distinct perfect matchings.
3. Lose this property if any edge is deleted.

Comment: Misha, what if there were more than two perfect matchings? Why is maximum degree still 2 in that case?

Comment: @BMac If there are other perfect matchings besides $M_1$ and $M_2$, this doesn't change the argument. We know that there are at least two perfect matchings, and we pick any two of them to call $M_1$ and $M_2$. It follows from there that all edges are contained in $M_1 \cup M_2$ (deleting an edge not in $M_1 \cup M_2$ would leave both of these intact, so the graph wouldn't be minimally $2$-matchable, and therefore no such edge can exist), and it follows from *there* that maximum degree is $2$.

Comment: Oh, I see now, because if a given vertex had degree 3, we couldn't put all three of those edges into just two matchings, by definition.